# gathering specific rows from each submatrices or cell arrays

Tags: matlab, for-loop, matrix, row, submatrix

I hope to gather last lines from each submatrix or cell arrays.

- I have 17 x 20 cells in matrix name A.
- Each submatrices have different number of lines, but same number of columns (total 7 columns, all)
- I tried to generate a file, made up of only last rows of each submatrices. My target file's from will be

  ```
       M = [column1 column2 column3 column4 column5 column6 column7] 
       % made up of last rows of each submatrices, unknown number of lines, 7 columns
  ```
- So I tried

  ```
       for x_cc = 1:20
           for y_cc = 1:17
                M = A{x_cc, y_cc}(end,:);
           end
       end
  ```
- But it is not working, giving the error Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
- Should I need to define the size first? What operation should be done? or what commands are useful? I tried cellfun, but not sure how can I use here.
- Need any help to solve this situation. Thanks~!

Answer (score 2):

First off, it looks like you switched `x_cc` and `y_cc`. Since your matrix is 17 x 20, `x_cc` is the rows and should go to 17, while `y_cc` will go to 20.

However, the error you're getting is probably coming from trying to index an empty array (one of those contained in A) using `end`. An example of this error:

```
a = [];

a(end)
??? Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

If you're curious, a method avoiding `for` loops would look like:

```
B = cellfun(@(x) x(end,:), A, 'UniformOutput', 0);  
M = cell2mat(B(:));
```

This grabs the last row from each matrix in A, then stacks them vertically and transforms to an array.

Comment: Thanks~! But could you tell me what is the x in here?

Comment: and for loop is still not working, though I followed your instruction, same error.

Comment: The x is a dummy variable. Kind of like saying "let's call each array in A 'x', then index it like x(end,:)."

Comment: Thanks~! but there is empty cells in my matrix A, that causes error for cellfun command. How can I ignore empty cells?

Comment: I've been trying to come up with a way to ignore the empties, but for now, you're better off removing them ahead of time or checking for them in the for loop before trying to index into them.